# Entity Framework 6 pluralises tablename when not required

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am using EF 6 and code first in my application.
I have a table called FaultClosedBy created by Code First.
However in my code where I want to do a simple query of the table, it is looking for a non-existent table called FaultClosedBies. 
So how do I fix this?
See [image]

Comment: Specify the table name explicitly (with data annotation / fluent config)? Disable EF table name pluralization globally? Not sure what you mean by *when not required*.

Comment: This particular table I did not want pluralised, that is what I meant. In this case the pluralised name does not make sense in English.

Comment: Well, I guess that's the defect of the pluralization method implementation (no one is perfect). Apply `[Table(FaultClosedBy")]` data annotation on `FaultClosedBy` class or `modelBuilder.Entity<FaultClosedBy>().ToTable("FaultClosedBy");` fluent configuration and move on.

Comment: So Ivan is right, the problem is solved by using a Table annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivan Stoev got the right answer in his comments under my question:

"Apply [Table(FaultClosedBy")] data annotation on FaultClosedBy class or modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable("FaultClosedBy");"